# Why not create dynamic pointer of derived class than to base class?

Tags: java, c++, polymorphism

```
class horse{/*some data and functions*/}
class bird{/*some data and functions*/}
class pegasus : public horse, public bird
{}
```

If classes are present as above, then in main why do I create like below mentioned

1) `horse *temp = new pegasus;`

instead I will create like

2) `pegasus *temp = new pegasus;`

In second method I can access functions of horse and bird, all functions including non virtuals where are in first method I can't access non virtual functions of pegasus object.

Comment: In (1) the compiler knows you have a horse, it doesn't know it is actually a pegasys, so it only lets you do horse things. In (2) the compiler knows you have a pegasys so you can do pagasys things. What is the question?

Comment: Why is this tagged Java?

Comment: in java, the famous example is `List list = new ArrayList()` -- the question is why not declare the variable type as `ArrayList`. My opinion is, indeed, it should be `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

You use the first approach when you need to treat your `pegasus` object like a `horse`, pretending that you do not know that it is also a `bird`. As long as you can do it, you should, because it lets you change the implementing class without changing anything else. This is called *programming to interface*.

You use the second approach when you need to use both the `horse` and the `bird` aspects of your `pegasus` object. This places tighter constraints on the objects that you can assign to `tmp`, because it must provide implementations of both classes.